# ¿Cómo debo abreviar la "tecnología de la información"?

Tags: abreviaturas, informática

Estoy creando un sitio web para una pequeña empresa que tiene algunos enlaces que se refieren a (en inglés) "IT" (**i**nformation **t**echnology, o sea en español, tecnología de la información).

En inglés, se usa las siglas "TI" para abreviar "information technology", pero en español, ¿se puede escribir "TI" (**t**ecnología de la **i**nformación) para decir la misma cosa?

¿O hay una mejor manera de abreviar la "tecnología de la información" en español?

---

I am creating a website for a small company that has some links referring to (in English) "information technology".

In English, "information technology" is abbreviated "IT", but in Spanish, is it "TI"?

Or is there a better way of abbreviating "information technology" in Spanish?

An example is a link which in English reads “IT Staff Directory”. I'm wondering whether in Spanish having that link read “**Directorio de personal de TI**” would be appropriate.

Comment: Could you give us the exact context, i.e. the sentence in English where you mention IT?  I checked Linguee and found the following equivalents for "IT" (as in "IT has been working on my computer all morning and I haven't been able to get any work done"): *servicio informático, departamento de informática, departamento de TI* (but here I don't know if one would say the letters, or pronounce it like the word "ti"), and occasionally  *departamento de IT*.

Comment: An example is a link when in English reads "IT Staff Directory". I'm wondering if "Directorio de personal de TI" would be appropriate.

Comment: Es muy frecuente, por influencia del francés, escuchar simplemente *informática* como término que engloba *information technology* y *computer science*. Así tenemos un *departamento de informática* (I.T. Departament)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*TI*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnolog%C3%ADa_de_la_informaci%C3%B3n) según Wikipedia. Si no, se puede usar *IT* que también es aceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que "Directorio de personal de TI" se podría entender.  Quizás sería un poquito mejor

> Directorio del departamento de T.I.  (Puse los puntos para que se pronuncien las dos letras.)

o

> Directorio del servicio informático

Answer (score 0):

Coincido con lo dicho por guifa en los comentarios: por influencia del francés (desconocía este matiz), es común utilizar solamente *informática*.

*IT* se usa por influencia directa inglesa y *TI* lo he visto utilizado en organismos oficiales ([CTTI](http://ctti.gencat.cat/ca/inici/) - *Centre de Telecomunicacions i Tecnologies de la Informació*, organismo catalán cuyo nombre se traduce como *Centro de Telecomunicaciones y Tecnologías de la Información*). También es común encontrarse con *TIC* (*Tecnologías de la Información y la Comunicación*) en el ámbito educativo, cuando hablan de competencias de los alumnos.

Sin embargo, fuera de estos ámbitos es raro encontrar *TI* y la gente no lo reconocerá inmediatamente. Para evitar, pues, la duda, puedes indicar:

> Directorio del departamento de informática.

O incluso directamente usar lo siguiente si se trata de una empresa en la que los informáticos son los únicos técnicos:

> Directorio del deparatamento tecnológico